# How to check if it's a CLR Class Library or Silverlight Class library?

Tags: .net, silverlight

This might sound weird, but when I open a solution that I dont know, how do I determine if a class library is just plain CLR class library or actually a silverlight class library?

Thanks,
Kave

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may take a look at the version of the referenced `mscorlib` assembly. For Silverlight 4.0 it will be 2.0.5.0. Also when you go to the properties of the class library project you will see that it is Silverlight. Also Visual Studio uses different icons to represent them:

[image]

Also if you open the corresponding `.csproj` you will notice that a Silverlight project library has the following GUIDs which are used by Visual Studio to make the distinction:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{A1591282-1198-4647-A2B1-27E5FF5F6F3B};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```